# How to show/hide item depending on its value in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to display a value if it exists, but if it doesn't exist I just need to display a + icon to potentially add it.

```
   <tr *ngFor="let set of trainingTemplateExercises.data.sets; index as i">
    <td *ngIf="set.note">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="set.note" name="value" class="form-control" /> 
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="!set.note">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="set.note" name="value" class="form-control" /> 
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="!set.note">
       <p> ANY PLUS ICON example +  </p 
    </td>
   </tr>
```

Example:
If set.note exist show.

If no exist print text 'Any plus icon example +'.

If set.note is added but you want to remove add '-' icon.
I try with toggle but no chance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the *ngIf Else syntax.

```
<tr *ngFor="let set of trainingTemplateExercises.data.sets; index as i">
   <div *ngIf="set.note else add">
      <td>
         <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="set.note" name="value" class="form-control" /> 
      </td>
   </div>
   <ng-template #add>
       <td>
         <p> ANY PLUS ICON example +  </p 
       </td>
   </ng-template>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let set of trainingTemplateExercises.data.sets; index as i">
    <div *ngIf="set.note;else add">
        <td *ngIf="!set.id; else edit">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="set.note" name="value" class="form-control" /> 
        </td>  
        <ng-template #edit>
        <td>
            <p> ANY MINUS ICON example -  </p>
        </td>
    </ng-template>          
    </div>
    <ng-template #add>
        <td>
            <p> ANY PLUS ICON example +  </p>
        </td>
    </ng-template>
</tr>
```